# Keep specific values in a dataframe and delete all the others

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, vectorization

Starting from a dataframe like this:

```
  col1 <- c("Anne", "Emma", "Katy", "Albert", "Richard")
  col2 <- c("Albert", "Mark", "Mike", "Loren", "Anne")
  col3 <- c("Mark", "Emma", "Paul", "George", "Samuel" )
  
  df <- cbind(col1, col2, col3)
```

I would like to keep only the values reported in this vector:

```
selected <- c("Emma", "Katy", "Mark")
```

and delete all the others, in order to have a new dataframe like this:

```
col1    col2    col3
NA      NA      "Mark"
"Emma"  "Mark"  "Emma"
"Katy"  NA      NA
NA      NA      NA
NA      NA      NA
```

I have tried with the following code and it works:

```
df[df != "Emma" & df != "Katy" & df != "Mark"] <- NA
```

but I would like to find a way to use the vector `selected` in an if statement, instead of writing all the conditions manually.
Indeed, my actual dataframe and vector of values are bigger than the ones in this example.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You want `%in%` - like `x %in% selected` I imagine. Could you clarify if your `df` is a `data.frame` however? In your example you used `cbind()` which makes a `matrix` instead. That will change how the code needs to be structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question creates a matrix with `cbind`, not a data.frame. This is important because df's are lists of vectors all of the same length with a dim attribute set whereas matrices are a folded vector, a vector with a dim attribute set.

- For data.frames, use a loop over its columns, applying function `'%in%'` to each of them;
- For matrices, there's no need for a loop.

```r
col1 <- c("Anne", "Emma", "Katy", "Albert", "Richard")
col2 <- c("Albert", "Mark", "Mike", "Loren", "Anne")
col3 <- c("Mark", "Emma", "Paul", "George", "Samuel" )

mat <- cbind(col1, col2, col3) 
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3) 

selected <- c("Emma", "Katy", "Mark")

is.na(df) <- !sapply(df, `%in%`, selected)
df
#>   col1 col2 col3
#> 1 <NA> <NA> Mark
#> 2 Emma Mark Emma
#> 3 Katy <NA> <NA>
#> 4 <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 5 <NA> <NA> <NA>

is.na(mat) <- !mat %in% selected
mat
#>      col1   col2   col3  
#> [1,] NA     NA     "Mark"
#> [2,] "Emma" "Mark" "Emma"
#> [3,] "Katy" NA     NA    
#> [4,] NA     NA     NA    
#> [5,] NA     NA     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks Rui for your detailed answer! It works as I expected. Actually I have a dataframe and I have improperly created a matrix for this example. However, I found useful to know the difference between df and matrix for what concern %in% operator.